# Where can I find the tax waiver rules for New Jersey?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, new-jersey, trusts-and-estates

A person dies in the state of New Jersey. When do you have to file form L-4?

Note: It seems to me that if all the beneficiaries are class A then there is no real need to file form L-4 because there is no tax due. However, I do not know what the law says in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When do you have to file form L-4?**

When one of the conditions for [Form L-4](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/other_forms/inheritance/itl4.pdf) *Affidavit Requesting Preliminary Waivers: Resident Decedents* are met:

> - A complete Inheritance or Estate Tax return cannot be completed yet; or
> - **All beneficiaries are Class A, but estate does not qualify to use Form L-8**; or
> - All beneficiaries are Class E, or Class E and Class A.

For awareness, Form [L-8](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/other_forms/inheritance/itl8.pdf) *Affidavit for Non-Real Estate Investments: Resident Decedents* is for the release of:

> - New Jersey bank accounts;
> - Stock in New Jersey corporations;
> - Brokerage accounts; and
> - New Jersey investment bonds.

NB, L-8 cannot be used for real estate, which requires [Form L-9](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/other_forms/inheritance/itl9.pdf) *Affidavit for Real Property Tax Waiver Resident Decedent*